# Android APK and root devices. Not allow to share the application

Tags: android, security, google-play, apk

I 'm going to publish a not free APK in Google Play.

If the user device is root, the user can share the APK as "free" to other users

How can I manage this situation to control if the user has paid for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implement google app licensing in your app.

Which will give you a result as user has not installed this application from google play store and above it you can handle your logic for not to go further in app.

[Google App Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use it